# How do I reuse SQLiteCpp SQLite::Statement?

Tags: c++, sqlite

SQLiteCpp is a open sourced library for operating sqlite database. Here's an [example](https://git.tk.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/SPIN/ID2T-toolkit/src/v0.1.0/code_boost/src/SQLiteCpp/README.md).

```
try
{
    // Open a database file
    SQLite::Database    db("example.db3");
    
    // Compile a SQL query, containing one parameter (index 1)
    SQLite::Statement   query(db, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE size > ?");
    
    // Bind the integer value 6 to the first parameter of the SQL query
    query.bind(1, 6);
    
    // Loop to execute the query step by step, to get rows of result
    while (query.executeStep())
    {
        // Demonstrate how to get some typed column value
        int         id      = query.getColumn(0);
        const char* value   = query.getColumn(1);
        int         size    = query.getColumn(2);
        
        std::cout << "row: " << id << ", " << value << ", " << size << std::endl;
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Since the query is passed in the constructor of Statement `SQLite::Statement   query(db, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE size > ?");`, how do I reuse it?

I didn't see a method accepts a string like `query.setQuery("select * from table")`. Do you know how do I reuse it?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to "reuse" a Statement object for a different query? What do you hope to gain by that?

Comment: I encountered this when I wanted do comparison for 2 table structures, `PRAGMA table_info(tb1)`. I wanted to store table column names one after another. After I can't reuse the query. I just created another to go on. `Statement query1(...); Statement query2(...)`, I thought it's kind of dull.

Answer (score 0):

If it bothers you that much you can just reassign it:

```
query = SQLite::Statement{db, "select * from table"};
```